# Edit-компонент для чисел

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, Edit-компонент для чисел, чтобы числа в нем всегда заканчивались на "," (или точка) и две цифры.

Comment: Я же писал, как можно это сделать? Не знаете, как код написать?  

Я просто не думаю, что кто-то специально делал библиотеку с компонентами, которые бы дублировали Edit и добавляли к его возможностям такие элементарные вещи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ладно, я раньше занимался этим, так что приведу пример кода.

Где-нибудь создаете класс:

```
type
  TMyEdit = class(TEdit)  // этот класс у нас будет отвечать за правостороннее расположение чисел в поле ввода
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);override;
  end;
```

и описываете процедуру:

```
procedure TMyEdit.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.Style:=Params.Style or ES_RIGHT;
end;
```

При создании формы прописываете это у всех финансовых Edit'ов, чтобы числа отображались справа:

```
 pPointer(Edit3)^:=TMyEdit;
 TMyEdit(Edit3).RecreateWnd;
```

Пишите обработчики для финансовых Edit'ов:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit3Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Edit3.Text = '0.00' then // ну тут все ясно
    Edit3.Text:= '';
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit3Exit(Sender: TObject);
var
  Text: string;
begin
  Text:= Edit3.Text;
  if Pos('.', Edit3.Text) = 0 then // если пользователь не указал копейки, то добавляем нули вместе с точкой
    Edit3.Text:= Edit3.Text + '.00'
  else
    begin      
      Delete(Text, 1, Pos('.', Text)); 
      if length(Text) <= 2 then
        begin
          if Text = '' then
            Edit3.Text:= Edit3.Text + '00'
          else
            begin
              Delete(Text, 1, pos(text[1], text));
              if Text = '' then
                Edit3.Text:= Edit3.Text + '0'
            end;
        end
      else
        begin // если много цифр после точки, то обрезаем их
          Text:= Copy(Text, 3, Length(Text));
          Edit3.Text:= Copy(Edit3.Text, 1, Length(Edit3.Text) - Length(Text));
        end;
    end;
  if Edit3.Text[1] = '.' then
    Edit3.Text:= '0.00'
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit3KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  Text: string;
begin
  if (Edit3.Text = '') and (key in [#46]) then
    Key:= #0;

  // Настройка  маски ввода для поля
  if not (Key in ['0'..'9', #8, #46]) or
  ((Pos('.', Edit3.Text) <> 0) and (Key in [#46])) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Comment: писал это давно, вроде работает =/

Comment: Спасибо, teanЫЧ!